# How to resolve Execution failed task ':app:checkDebugAarMetaData' error in a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter

When I run my flutter application this error comes
I use VS code as editor and bluestacks as emulator
Please help me resolve this
I didn't update or change the version of flutter recently
flutter doctor
I didn't try much to solve this issue as I couldn't find anything on web

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.10.2 on channel stable at C:\Users\admin\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9cd3d0d9ff (8 days ago), 2023-05-23 20:57:28 -0700
    • Engine revision 90fa3ae28f
    • Dart version 3.0.2
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-9586694)

[√] VS Code (version 1.78.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.64.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2965]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 113.0.5672.127
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 113.0.1774.57

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

My debug console

```
Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...
Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS A5000 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/firebase/firebase-bom/28.3.0/firebase-bom-28.3.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/firebase/firebase-bom/28.3.0/firebase-bom-28.3.0.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/firebase/firebase-bom/28.3.0/firebase-bom-28.3.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 35s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)`
```

My android Level build.gradle

```
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
      reposiories {
        googlet()
        mavenCentral()
     }

      dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
         classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        
     }
  }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir

}
```

My App level build.gradle

```
  
`def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.keshav_application"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.keshav_application"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```